# ReciclerView android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un proyecto y no acabo de saber editarlo.

El problema que tengo es que necesito un título y una descripción.
Pero ahora mismo tanto el título como la descripción se rellenan con la misma información.
Como lo modifico? que tengo que hacer?

Os pongo el código:

El main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> dades = new ArrayList<String>();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rView);
clerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Adaptador adapter = new Adaptador(this, dades);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        for(int i = 2; i <= 1; i++){
            dades.add(new String("Dada " + i));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Adaptador:

```
public class Adaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.ElMeuViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private Context context;

    public Adaptador(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items= items;
    }

    @Override
    public Adaptador.ElMeuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fila, null);
        ElMeuViewHolder viewHolder = new ElMeuViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ElMeuViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(position));
        viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(items.get(position));

    }

    public static class ElMeuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Només conté un TextView
        protected TextView vTitle;
        protected TextView vDescripcio;
        public ElMeuViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            vDescripcio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcio);

        }
    }
}
```

Ahora el resultado que me da es:

Dada1 (Titulo)
dada1 (descripción)

Me explico un poco mejor que creo que no se me ha entendido, me gustaría saber como puedo poner yo misma valores a titulo y a descripción.

```
Por ejemplo 
Titulo: Pelicula
Descripción: De cine

Titulo: Musical
Descripcion : De cine

Ahora mismo lo que tengo es:
Dada 0 
Dada 0

Dada 1 
Dada 1
```

Podéis ayudarme?

gracias!

Comment: El resultado que sale es Dada1 para título y dada1 para el campo descripción? No me cuadra, debería salir "Dada 2" en ambos casos

Comment: si perdón! Pero eso no afecta en mi pregunta T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El objeto `dades` de tipo `ArrayList<String>` contiene un sólo elemento que se asigna en el bucle `for`:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 1; i++){
   dades.add(new String("Dada " + i));
}
```

Como la variable `i` se le asigna valor inicial 2, el bucle sólo recorre una iteración. Al terminar la primera pasada, el valor de `i` se incrementa, y al comprobar la condición `i<=1`, el bucle finaliza ya que en ese momento `i=3`.

Posteriormente, en:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ElMeuViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

   viewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(position));
   viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(items.get(position));
}
```

Al campo `vTitle` y al campo `vDescripcio` se les está asignado el mismo valor `items.get(position)` ya que la variable `position` tiene el mismo valor.

Para añadir diferentes valores y no producir ningun error por desbordamiento, lo primero sería modificar el bucle for para añadir en `dades` dos valores diferentes, por ejemplo, iniciando la variable i con valor 0:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
   dades.add(new String("Dada " + i));
}
```

De esta manera tendremos dos Strings ("Dada 0" y "Dada 1") en el objeto `dades`.

Después, para tener un valor diferente en `vTitle`y `vDescripcio` basta con incrementar el valor de la variable `position` con `position + 1` para la descripción como en el siguiente código:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ElMeuViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

   viewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(position));
   viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(items.get(position + 1));
}
```

De esta manera, a `vTitle` se le asignaria el primer elemento de `items` "Dada 0" y a `vDescripcio` el segundo "Dada 1"

**EDITO**

Dejo la parte anterior para que queden las aclaraciones del bucle y la asignación a `vTitle`y `vDescripcio`

Si lo que quieres es poner valores tú misma a esos campos, entonces no te hace falta el bucle `for`.

Añade dos elementos a dades con la cadena que tú quieres:

```
...
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

dades.add(new String("Título: Película));
dades.add(new String("Descripción: De cine"));

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

...

En la asignación a las variables título y descripción, sólo tendrías que utilizar position como indiqué anteriormente:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ElMeuViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

   viewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(position));
   viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(items.get(position + 1));
}
```

Podrías crear una matriz de arrays, y asignar manualmente varios valores para tener diferentes opciones según la posición del `RecyclerView`, y usando un bucle `for`:

Declaras dades como una matriz de `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dades = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Creas un objeto ArrayList que tenga dos valores, uno para título y otro para la descripción:

```
ArrayList<String> elemento;
```

En un bucle for, añades los valores de cada campo y añades el elemento creado a dades:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    dade = new ArrayList<String>();
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            dade.add(new String("Titulo: Película"));
            dade.add(new String("Descripción: de cine"));
        break;
        case 1: 
            dade.add(new String("Titulo: Musical"));
            dade.add(new String("Descripción: de cine"));
        break;
    }   
    dades.add(dade);
}
```

Modificas en el adaptador el objeto items y obtienes los elementos en el bind:

```
...
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> items;

...

public Adaptador(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items= items;
}
...
public void onBindViewHolder(ElMeuViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

   ArrayList<String> elemento = new ArrayList<String>();
   elemento = items.get(position);

   viewHolder.vTitle.setText(elemento(0));
   viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(elemento(1));
}
...
```

Comment: Error mío, creo que no me he explicado bien.. Quiero poder asignarle un valor diferente. 
Es decir por ejemplo Dada 1 Descripcion hola  Dada 2 Descripcion Que tal

Comment: he editado explicando mejor.

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo, en Titulo quieres poder poner por ejemplo Dada 1y en descripción por ejemplo "hola"?

Comment: si eso mismo. Que no se repita el mismo valor. Poder ser yo quien decida que va en casa cosa.

Comment: me da este error _:   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at e.a.proyecto3.Adaptador.onBindViewHolder(Adaptador.java:48)
        at e.a.proyecto3.Adaptador.onBindViewHolder(Adaptador.java:13)

Comment: ¿como has asignado los valores en dades? ¿Que has usado en el onBindViewHolder?

Comment: el problema es que no puedo usar un switch por que necesito que sean introducidos por consola es decir se tienen que poder eliminar y añadir..

Comment: en el onBind tengo esto:    public void onBindViewHolder(ElMeuViewHolder viewHolder, int position ) {
        /* *
         * position conté la posició de l'element actual a la llista. També l'utilitzarem
         * com a índex per a recòrrer les dades
         * */
        viewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(position));
        viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(items.get(position ));

Comment: Y como has inicializado el array dades? Cuantos valores has asignado?. El error te dice que estas accediendo al índice 2, pero sólo hay dos elementos (que serían el índice 0 y el 1)

Comment: el programa lo tienes arriba, no tengo más clases ni nada.. :S

Comment: Entonces estás ejecutando el código tal cual lo tienes arriba? no has hecho ningún cambio adicional a lo que hay arriba en tú pregunta?

Comment: no. Tal como esta. He incorporado cosas tuyas como el posicion +1 que no funciona. He modificado el for. Pero sigue igual ahora mismo.

Comment: Y el error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2` te ha dado con tú código original o con los cambios que incorporaste de cosas mías?

Comment: Depura el código y comprueba los valores de position, dades  e items

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84342/discussion-between-devcodeg-and-montse-mkd).

Comment: sigo con problremas.. es decir el position + 1 me da error.. :S

Comment: Suponiendo que items contenga dos elementos, el título y la descripción, utiiliza en vez de position, los valores 0 para título y 1 para descripción. `viewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(position));` y `viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(items.get(position + 1));`. Si tu programa permite introducir por teclado más de un elemento (titulo:descripcion) utiliza una matriz de arrays como te indico en el ejemplo cambiando la parte del switch por tu código donde se pide al usuario que introduzca los valores.

Comment: el problema es que position + 1 me da error.

Comment: perdón, en la respuesta anterior, el trozo de código que quería ponerte es `viewHolder.vTitle.setText(items.get(0));` y `viewHolder.vDescripcio.setText(items.get(1));`, es decir, en el primer caso sustitye `position`por 0 y en el segundo sustituye `position+1` por 1