# Quitar Switch case por un for?

Tags: java, android-studio

no sé como afrontar lo siguiente:

Tengo la siguiente parte de código:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            ArrayList<String> dade = new ArrayList<String>();
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    dade.add(new String("1-"));
                    dade.add(new String("a)"));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    dade.add(new String("2-"));
                    dade.add(new String("b)"));
                    break;
            }
            dades.add(dade);
        }
```

La idea es que relleno el array strings con 2 datos. 
Es decir por pantalla me muestra ahora lo siguiente

1-
a)

2-
b)

El problema es que no quiero que sea usando Switch / Case ya que los datos se tienen que rellenar manualmente. Y no quiero que haya un máximo..

Como puedo hacerlo? Sé que es una pregunta extensa pero no sé como plantearlo.

El usuario introducirá dos datos y se pondran en un recyclerView.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir el resultado de la pantalla es el siguiente que es lo que necesito. El problema es que esos datos los introduce el usuario y yo tengo un swtich case. Espero explicarme ahora mejor.

gracias!

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que quieres hacer; parece un clásico problema X-Y (quiero saber cómo hacer X para resolver Y). Con una perspectiva *amplia* ¿qué intentas conseguir?

Comment: Una construccion FOR.. SWITCH, quiere decir que algo esta mal. Cual es el sentido de recorrer un array, si en cada caso vas a hacer algo diferente?

Comment: Cómo tienes definido `dades`? A mí me parece un problema tipo Par-Impar...

Comment: ahora pongo que quiero conseguir.

Comment: Sería interesante que digas dónde construyes `dade` y por qué en su origen ese objeto no tiene ya el dato que intentas agregarle en los `case`. No digo que tenga que ser así, pero pregunto por curiosidad y porque a veces pudiendo tener los objetos mejor estructurados nos complicamos la vida manipulándolos para arriba y para abajo... Parece algo demasiado básico y hasta ilógico lo que haces, porque en el `switch`  lo que haces es comparar el valor de `i`.  ¿Qué relación tiene `i`  con `dade`, por qué en unos casos debes agregar `-1` y en otros `-2`...?

Comment: acabo de poner más información ya me diréis! ^^

Comment: Lamentablemente *no te has explicado mejor*. Esto suena a algo bastante sencillo de hacer, pero la forma en que intentas resolverlo me parece que es complicada. ¿Podrías dar una explicación general, sin tener que ceñirte al código que estás implementando? O sea, olvida tu código por un momento y explica lo que quieres hacer sólo con palabras. *El usuario pone tales datos y a partir de esos datos tengo que...*

Comment: Mi programa se trata de crear una lista utilizando una RecyclerView. El usuario tendra que rellenar la lista con 2 datos. ( 1 es un titulo y el 2 una descripción) de ahí el ejemplo de la foto. El 1 es el título y la letra es la descripción.

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver los datos que ingresa el usuario con ese codigo que no tiene casi sentido de ser. Si tiene que agregar datos a una clase, cual es el problema?

Comment: Que lo mejor que he sabido hacerlo es de esta forma.. por eso pido ayuda.. :S

Comment: todo viene desde aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203744/reciclerview-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment381124_203744

Comment: Ok amigo usted primero tiene que mencionar el patrón que debe seguir la generación de estos `strings`. Al parecer tienes una lista y una sub-lista, la lista se genera de forma numérica y vendría siendo algo así como "1.- 2.- 3.-", etc. y la sublista (contenida por la lista) se arma con las letras del abecedario => "a) b) c).." etc. No se si este es el patrón que hay que seguir pero **te aconsejo cambiar la pregunta por completo reestructurando, en primer lugar pones lo que necesitas hacer (el recycleviewer que tendra tal estructura) y después agregas lo que intentaste y como quieres hacerlo**

Comment: tal cual esta tu pregunta no se entiende mucho, quizás ninguna de las aproximaciones a las que llegaste o quieres llegar sea la idónea, mejor indica que es lo que necesitas hacer

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Lo que hace el siguiente codigo es agregar de manera automatica (hasta un limite de 27) las letras en el orden que pide:
1-a)
2-b) 
etc.
Se crear un arreglo con las letras necesarias:*/
    String[] abc = new String{"a","b","c",....};
/*    Agregas un limite para el for Puse 27 por las letras del abecedario*/

        for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++){
                ArrayList<String> dade = new ArrayList<String>();
/*Aqui se hace una contatenacion de los datos, (i+1) es para que que no empiece a contar desde el 0.*/


  dade.add(new String((i+1) +"-" +abc[i] + ")"));
            dades.add(dade);
        }
```

Comment: podrías explicar que hace tu código, para que tu respuesta sea mas completa y la gente que venga pueda entender. Saludos!

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez lo siento estaba ocupado e hice el codigo bastante rapido.

Comment: gracia spor la ayuda, pero no es lo que necesito. He puesto 1, 2 y A, b como podría haber puesto otra cosa. Es decir es información que pondré el usuario. son datos que no siguen un patrón.

Comment: ¿porqué hacer una lista con cada letra? si se puede perfectamente con chars

Comment: Es preferible que las respuestas de código tengan una explicación para que sean bien recibidas en la comunidad. Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

No termino de entender tu pregunta,
Necesitas poder hacer una lista de listas con 2 valores con el formato X-Y) 
donde X es numero e Y es una letra del abecedario, no?

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    ArrayList<String> dade = new ArrayList<String>();
    dade.add(String.valueOf((i+1)+"-"));
    if(i+65<=90){
        dade.add(String.valueOf(((char)(i+65))+")"));
    }else{
        int hlpr = i/26; // cuantas veces nos pasamos de la Z?
        if(hlpr<2){
            String aux = String.valueOf(((char)(hlpr+64)));
            int j = (i - (25*hlpr))+64;
            j = j<0? j*-1 : j;
            aux+=String.valueOf(((char)(j)));
            dade.add(String.valueOf(aux+")"));
        }else{
            //ya si te pasas de 2 veces, quizás necesites una función recursiva para seguir añadiendo Letras
        }
    }
    dades.add(dade);
}
```

de ser así, con un ciclo mas o menos así, debieras poder añadir letras según el `size` entregado, ocupando `char` los cuales su valor numérico se rige por la tabla [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda  no todas las preguntas pueden o deben responderse. Lo mejor es pedir aclaraciones al OP mediante comentarios acerca de la pregunta para que esta pueda ser entendible y valiosa a la comunidad, saludos.